# Data driven forms, loop radiobutton with default value not working with validation?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a reactive form, looping out some data. I want to set the default values of the radiobuttons here. Its works, but the validation not working.

```
    <fieldset *ngIf="question.radioButtonList.length > 0">
      <div class="choice-list">
        <div *ngFor="let item of question.radioButtonList" class="choice-list-item">
          <input type="radio" [name]="choice" formControlName="choice" [id]="item.id" [value]="item.id" [checked]="question.answer.selectedChoiceId === item.id"/>
          <label>{{item.title}}</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
```

And in my form definition i set the formControlName to have a required validator.

```
 'choice': new FormControl('',Validators.required)
```

The thing is that the radiobutton is checked correctly in the loop but the validator say it's invalid. Until i manually click on a radiobutton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you set the initial value as empty string in your form control which is evaluated as valid. It ignores `[checked]` in your template. So you need to set the initial value when you create the form control:

```
'choice': new FormControl(someInitialValueHere, Validators.required)
```

*(BTW, you wouldn't need the `required` validation here, since this is a radio button and cannot be unchecked)*

if you cannot set the initial value when building the form, you can use `patchValue`

```
this.myForm.patchValue({choice: someValue})
```

This will set the default value as what you want, this though means that you would have to do the logic to set your default value (corresponding your `[checked]` logic). Seems like you need to do some looping perhaps to find out which default value you want.